# Pattern or approach for accessing parent object properties deeper in the object graph

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mapping

We have scenarios where objects that are 'deeper' in the object graph need to have values updated based on the value of an ancestor.  E.g. consider a mapping exercise where we are mapping values of an object that is coming in from a web view.  We have the original persisted object as it exists in the database/store, and we have the mutated object that is coming in from the view.  Given the 'schema' below for a visual, if we are mapping the incoming object from the view to a persisted 'twin' from the database, and we want to set the value of the coverage deductible based on the value of the policy default deductible, is there a way to do this without passing along a reference to the parent object?

```
{
   Policy: {
     DefaultDeducitble: 1000
     LocationCollection: [{ 
           Location: {
            BuildingCollection: [{
               Building: {
                CoverageCollection: [{
                  Coverage: { DefaultDeductible: nulll}
                }]
              }
          }]
          }
       }]
  }
}
```

Our mappers map one level of an objects hierarchy, so we would have something like:

```
class PolicyMapper { /// maps policy and calls a location collection mapper }
class LocationCollectionMapper { /// calls a location mapper for each location }
class LocationMapper {///maps the location and calls building collection mapper }
class BuildingCollectionMapper { /// calls a building mapper for each building }
class BuidlingMapper {///maps the buidling and calls coverage collection mapper }
class CoverageCollectionMapper { /// calls a coverage mapper for each coverage }
class CoverageMapper {///maps the coverage, this is where we want a value from the Policy level }
```

So the questionwould be, how can we access the Policy level information in the CoverageMapper without passing the the Policy object throughout the mapping hierarchy?  One idea was to have a transient cache that we can query.  I don't really know if this exists...or if this is a good idea or an antipattern...however it would look something like:

```
public class TransientPolicyCache {
   ///code to load the cache and retreive stuff
   public Policy Get() { //returns the policy  }
}

public class CoverageMapper {
   public CovergaeMapper(TransientPolicyCache cache) { ///cache is provided by ioc }

   public Coverage Map(Coverage target, Coverage source){  
     //need the policy
     var policy = _cache.Get();
    // do the things
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I do not fully understand, but should the responsibility of setting a default value of the coverage deductible to match the policy level deductible, not reside further up the chain, and when you call `SetDefaultDeductible()` on it, it walks down the object hierarchy and updates the coverage deductible.

Comment: @Rakesh That is the approach we are currently taking.  Mapping occurs and it is 1:1.  After mapping post processing occurs and is keeping the concerns of mapping, and setting defaults with rules separate.

Comment: What about the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface?

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me a lot of WPF's [Dependancy Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-implement-a-dependency-property).

- Every Instance in the Visual Tree can be given a value, including stuff that lacks this property.
- If a instance has no value, it works up the visual tree until it finds one on anything.
- If there is still nothing found, the default will be used. Of wich there is only 1 Instance in the entire Programm.

But I am unsure if they can really help you here.